# Lazy loading API requests in UITableview using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm new to swift and iOS Development. I want have 100 cells in my `UITableView` and each cell has a different API request that returns `JSON` data which I will save to the `CoreData` and then display in the `UITableView`. How do i handle this? I want to implement lazy loading but i have no idea how to do it in this case. Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: check information about `DispatchGroups` and `asyncTasks` in Swift. but it is really weird to have 100 requests per `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

**You Can loading table view in main_queue**

```
//Use swift 2.3
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.yourTableView.reloadData()
})

//Use swift 3
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```